# JavaFX equivalent of Swing SpringLayout

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I've been working with Swing and SpringLayout for a while now and I want to know if JavaFX has equvalent of Swing SpringLayout, as I plan on swapping to JavaFX soon for my personal projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX is not *Swing*. JavaFX does not have the concept of a `LayoutManager` like *Swing* does. In *Swing* you assign a layout manager to a `JPanel`, for example `BorderLayout`, but in JavaFX you use a `BorderPane` which is a container that uses a specific layout. I don't know whether JavaFX has a container that lays out its components like `SpringLayout` does but I doubt it. Possibly, [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) may be appropriate. In any case, the tutorial linked to in the other answer may help you discover an appropriate container.

Remember, you can't write JavaFX the same way you write *Swing*. You need to adapt to the JavaFX way of doing things. For example, JavaFX uses "bindings" while *Swing* uses "listeners".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, u can try this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html
It`s example to solve layout problem in javafx